# Split a tweet in python, received by the Twitter Streaming API

Tags: python, string, mongodb, twitter, split

I am using Twitter's Streaming API and i have received results in json type which i have imported in a mongoDb database via Python in order to perform queries. From the query results i have come up with a text file that contains the user id and the text of the tweet msg. The form is the following:

```
u'"#Fishing on the #Euphrates": http://t.co/sA1uGz8c2g. The shocking power of normality in #IS #propaganda, from @charliewinter @QuilliamF': 651322435355181056L,
```

i want to isolate the text part and the user_id. The ideal would be a python implementation that would produce a list with two entries.

```
list[0] = #Fishing on the #Euphrates": http://t.co/sA1uGz8c2g. The shocking power of normality in #IS #propaganda, from @charliewinter @QuilliamF

list[1] = 651322435355181056L
```

i am beginner in python and i would really appreciate any help! i've already tried the split() method but i cannot understand how to keep a whole sentence together and remove any punctuation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Read the lines of your text file into strings and you can use the split method. This will only work if the strings are consistent and the user id is always separated by the same character in this case a colon (:).

where

```
inP = str(u'"#Fishing on the #Euphrates": http://t.co/sA1uGz8c2g. The shocking power of normality in #IS #propaganda, from @charliewinter @QuilliamF': 651322435355181056L)

list = inP.split(:)
```

This will give you two values.

```
list[0] = u'#Fishing on the #Euphrates": http://t.co/sA1uGz8c2g. The shocking power of normality in #IS #propaganda, from @charliewinter @QuilliamF
list[1] = 651322435355181056L
```

then you can use the replace method:

```
rep = ['.',','] etc.
for i in rep:
 list[0] = list[0].replace(i, '')
```

There may be a faster way.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

To split the string by colon, you have to give the colon as the parameter to the split function:

```
inputStr = str(u'"#Fishing on the #Euphrates": http://t.co/sA1uGz8c2g. The shocking power of normality in #IS #propaganda, from @charliewinter @QuilliamF': 651322435355181056L)

inputStrSplit = inputStr.split(":")
```

To remove the punctuation from the first element of your list, use:

```
import string
outputStr = inputStrSplit[0].translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)
```